# How to use select with multiple elements?

Tags: python, selenium, automation, anaconda

I'm doing a report automation but I need to select several filters and when I select it it won't, the code follows:

```
b = chrome.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="Filters"]/div[1]/form/div[2]/div/div[10]/div/span/span[1]/span/ul')
c = Select(b)
c.select_by_visible_text('7474 - 0800 Berlanda')
```

So I selected all the options first to see how it looks when it's selected and it looks like this:

```
    <li class="select2-selection__choice" title=" 7474 - 0800 Berlanda  " data-select2-id="85"><span class="select2-selection__choice__remove" role="presentation">×</span> 7474 - 0800 Berlanda  </li>
    <li class="select2-selection__choice" title=" 9800 - 0800 JOSY MIX " data-select2-id="86"><span class="select2-selection__choice__remove" role="presentation">×</span> 9800 - 0800 JOSY MIX </li>
    <li class="select2-selection__choice" title=" 2222 - 0800 - Oi Vendas " data-select2-id="87"><span class="select2-selection__choice__remove" role="presentation">×</span> 2222 - 0800 - Oi Vendas </li>
    <li class="select2-selection__choice" title=" 6060 - 0800 MM " data-select2-id="88"><span class="select2-selection__choice__remove" role="presentation">×</span> 6060 - 0800 MM </li>
    <li class="select2-selection__choice" title=" 7070 - 0800 VUON CARD " data-select2-id="89"><span class="select2-selection__choice__remove" role="presentation">×</span> 7070 - 0800 VUON CARD </li>

I tried to copy the xpath of these options to see if that way he selected everything else didn't work, can you help me please?

**EDIT**

Here's the selection of the elements I'm trying to select:

<li class="select2-results__option" id="select2-ufab-result-kl9a-48" role="option" aria-selected="false" data-select2-id="select2-ufab-result-kl9a-48"> 7474 - 0800 Berlanda  </li>

<li class="select2-results__option" id="select2-ufab-result-9mym-54" role="option" aria-selected="false" data-select2-id="select2-ufab-result-9mym-54"> 9800 - 0800 JOSY MIX </li>

<li class="select2-results__option select2-results__option--highlighted" id="select2-ufab-result-bx84-62" role="option" aria-selected="false" data-select2-id="select2-ufab-result-bx84-62"> 2222 - 0800 - Oi Vendas </li>

<li class="select2-results__option" id="select2-ufab-result-1fdm-13" role="option" aria-selected="false" data-select2-id="select2-ufab-result-1fdm-13"> 6060 - 0800 MM </li>

<li class="select2-results__option" id="select2-ufab-result-zse8-199" role="option" aria-selected="false" data-select2-id="select2-ufab-result-zse8-199"> 7070 - 0800 VUON CARD </li>
```

Comment: Add more of the HTML, from `select` tag. Share the URL if possible.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've mistaken.

### Problem explanation :

See the **HTML**

```
<li class="select2-selection__choice" title=" 7474 - 0800 Berlanda  " data-select2-id="85"><span class="select2-selection__choice__remove" role="presentation">×</span> 7474 - 0800 Berlanda  </li>
```

there is a li tag that has a class `select2-selection__choice` and the class value is contains `select2`.

You can not use Select(b), since Select(web element) is for drop downs which are built using Select and option tag in HTML.

### Solution

1. You should directly click on drop down to open the options.
2. Once options are visible, directly click the one you want.

Something like this :

```
time.sleep(5)
b = chrome.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="Filters"]/div[1]/form/div[2]/div/div[10]/div/span/span[1]/span/ul')
b.click()

# Now options should be visible
time.sleep(5)
option = 
chrome.find_element_by_xpath("//li[contains(@text,'Berlanda')]")
option.click()
```

Comment: I tried to do it that way, it pops up the menu options but I didn't select any

I took the element without it selected and it appears like this:
  <li class="select2-results__option" id="select2-ww37-result-rh4q-48" role="option" aria-selected="false" data-select2-id="select2-ww37-result-rh4q-48 "> 7474 - 0800 Berlanda </li>

Comment: I have updated the code above, check it out and let me know if you run into any issues.

Comment: I tried that way and it didn't work, I tried to pull it straight through the option's xpath when the menu appears, but it still doesn't select, I edited the code showing how the options are without being selected.

Comment: hmm I reduced this xpath `//li[contains(@text,'Berlanda')]`, updated above as well, try and let me know

Comment: I managed to do it with one change, I got the full xpath I use the function you created for it to select the options and it works, it looks like this:

option1 = chrome.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/span/span/span/ul/li[1]')
option1.click()
b.click()
option2 = chrome.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/span/span/span/ul/li[3]')
option2.click()